# Shell Script: How to copy files with specific string from big corpus

Tags: bash, shell, ack

I have a small bug and don't know how to solve it. I want to copy files from a big folder with many files, where the files contain a specific string. For this I use grep, ack or (in this example) ag. When I'm inside the folder it matches without problem, but when I want to do it with a loop over the files in the following script it doesn't loop over the matches. Here my script:

```
ag -l "${SEARCH_QUERY}" "${INPUT_DIR}" | while read -d $'\0' file; do
    echo "$file"
    cp "${file}" "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${file}"
done
```

SEARCH_QUERY holds the String I want to find inside the files, INPUT_DIR is the folder where the files are located, OUTPUT_DIR is the folder where the found files should be copied to. Is there something wrong with the while do?

EDIT:
Thanks for the suggestions! I took this one now, because it also looks for files in subfolders and saves a list with all the files.

```
ag -l "${SEARCH_QUERY}" "${INPUT_DIR}" > "output_list.txt" 
while read file
do
    echo "${file##*/}"
    cp "${file}" "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${file##*/}"
done < "output_list.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Better implement it like below with a `find` command:

```
  find "${INPUT_DIR}" -name "*.*" | xargs grep -l "${SEARCH_QUERY}" > /tmp/file_list.txt

  while read file
  do
     echo "$file"
     cp "${file}" "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${file}"
  done < /tmp/file_list.txt
  rm /tmp/file_list.txt
```

or another option:

```
 grep -l "${SEARCH_QUERY}" "${INPUT_DIR}/*.*" > /tmp/file_list.txt 

 while read file
  do
     echo "$file"
     cp "${file}" "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${file}"
  done < /tmp/file_list.txt

  rm /tmp/file_list.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but I guess you mean "$line" instead of "$file" in the loop and I think "find" is quite slow with grep in a big folder? That's why I wanted to use ack or ag.

Comment: Yes I have just modified my answer with two options. First option will help you if you need to search files in sub directories as well.

Comment: Thanks, I took your 2nd option and modified a bit with "ag" (also takes subfolders). One of my problems in my old solution was, that I didn't delete the path of the origin file for the new one.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the [behavior of ag](https://www.mankier.com/1/ag) correctly, then you have to

- adjust the read delimiter to `'\n'` **or**
- use `ag -0 -l` to force delimiting by `'\0'`

to solve the problem in your loop.

Alternatively, you can use the following script, that is based on `find` instead of `ag`.

```
while read file; do
    echo "$file"
    cp "$file" "$OUTPUT_DIR/$file"
done < <(find "$INPUT_DIR" -name "*$SEARCH_QUERY*" -print)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you do not mind doing it in just **one line**, then

```
grep -lr 'ONE\|TWO\|THREE' | xargs -I xxx -P 0 cp xxx dist/
```

guide:

1. `-l` just print file name and nothing else
2. `-r` search **recursively** the CWD and all sub-directories
3. match these works alternatively: '*ONE*' or '*TWO*' or '*THREE*'
4. `|` pipe the output of `grep` to `xargs`
5. `-I xxx` name of the files is saved in `xxx` it is just an alias
6. `-P 0` run all the command (= `cp`) in parallel (= as fast as possible)
7. `cp` each file `xxx` to the `dist` directory